# CasperJS/PhantomJS not clearing cache in thenOpen

Tags: caching, phantomjs, casperjs

I am having a caching problem in CasperJS. Here is my code snippet.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
        verbose: true,
        logLevel: 'debug',
        pageSettings: {        
            loadImages:false,
            loadPlugins: false
        }
    });

casper.options.onResourceRequested = function(C, requestData, request) {
    if ((/https?:\/\/.+?\.css/gi).test(requestData['url']) || requestData['Content-Type'] == 'text/css') {
        //console.log('Skipping CSS file: ' + requestData['url']);
        request.abort();
    }
    else if ((/https?:\/\/.+?\.js/gi).test(requestData['url']) || requestData['Content-Type'] == 'text/javascript' || requestData['Content-Type'] == 'application/javascript') {
        //console.log('Skipping JS file: ' + requestData['url']);
        request.abort();
    }
}

    }
casper.on("resource.error", function(resourceError){
    console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
    console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
});


var cartlist_url = [
'http://secure.sandbox.thesitename.com/store_view/checkout/cart/add/sku/11111/category_id/CAT',
'http://secure.sandbox.thesitename.com/store_view/checkout/cart/add/sku/22222/category_id/CAT',
'http://secure.sandbox.thesitename.com/store_view/checkout/cart/add/sku/33333/category_id/CAT'
];
var selector = "table#thecart tbody tr td span.cart-price p:not(.old-price)";

casper.start();
casper.each(carturl_list, function(self, link) {    //this.thenOpen(link, function(){});
    this.thenOpen(link, function() {
        casper.page.clearMemoryCache();     
        this.echo(this.getHTML(selector).trim()match(/[0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+/)[0]);
    }); 
});
casper.run();
```

The sandbox urls are used to add a product directly to cart. After each time a product is added, the page automatically redirects to cart URL http://secure.sandbox.thesitename.com/store_view/checkout/cart/ I am working on a report page which first fetch the product page price (in a separate code, not here) and then fetch the cart page  price (the code here). The report page will show both prices to make sure that there are no differences. The issue is that the cart page prices are always the same as the first sku. The casperjs call is like this:

```
>casperjs addtocart.js --skulist=1111,22222,33333 --category=CAT
```

The prices are supposed to be 19.99, 18.99 and 19.99. But when I run the above command in console, all prices are 19.99, and if I change the skulist option to `--skulist=22222,11111,33333` then all the prices are displayed as 18.99. I have used `--disk-cache=false` but no effect. As per the post in [PhantomJS keeping cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390974/phantomjs-keeping-cache) there is a way to do it using `page.clearMemoryCache()` so I used it, but no effect. I wanted to append a random request parameter to the cart URL, but the redirection is automatic, and I cannot control it. As per a link (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10357) mentioned in the above post, the issue probably still persists. My `PhantomJS version is 2.1.1` and my `CasperJS version is 1.1.0-beta5`. Any help or workaround?

Comment: I took screenshots and found that each time the `casper.each` is using `casper.thenOpen` to open a cart URL with different SKUs, the sku is actually getting added to the same cart. I thought it is supposed to be separate sessions, but probably cookies are creating this issue. I resolved mine by using `casper.click` for the link to remove the product from cart before the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The issue described above is not caused by caching. Please see my comment.