# phantomJS crawling multi pages get misorder execution

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, web-crawler

I am using PhantomJS to crawling the pages generated from a inputstream.
But the resultjson and Headers always are {} even the status is 'success'(The first url can be ok , but usually the second one begins to be {}).Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;
var fs = require('fs');
var resultjson = {};
var Headers = {};
var urlType, url, path;
var isInUse = false;


function pageInit(page){
    page.settings.resourceTimeout = 500000;

    page.onResourceTimeout = function (request) {
        console.log("fail");
    }

    page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg, lineNum, sourceID) {
        //console.log(msg + "at line " + lineNum);
    }


    page.onResourceReceived = function (response) {
        if (response.url === url && response.stage === "end") {
            if (response.status === 301 && response.redirectURL !== null) {
                url = response.redirectURL;
            }
            else {
                resultjson.Id = response.id;
                resultjson.Url = response.url;
                resultjson.Time = response.time;
                resultjson.BodySize = response.bodySize;
                resultjson.ContentType = response.contentType;
                resultjson.RedirectURL = response.redirectURL;
                resultjson.Stage = response.stage;
                resultjson.Status = response.status;
                resultjson.StatusText = response.statusText;
                response.headers.forEach(function (header) {
                    Headers[header.name] = header.value;
                });
            }
        }
    };
}
function GetOtherPage(url, path) {
    page.open(url, function (status) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(resultjson));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(Headers));
        resultjson = {};
        Headers = {};
        if (status !== "success") {
            //fs.write(path, page.content, 'w');
            console.log("fail");
        }
        else {
            fs.write(path, page.content, 'w');
            console.log("success");
        }
        DoTask();
    });
}
function DoTask() {
    page.close();
    page = require('webpage').create();
    pageInit(page);
    //page.content = "";
    urlType = parseInt(system.stdin.readLine());
    if (urlType === -1)
        phantom.exit();
    url = system.stdin.readLine();
    path = system.stdin.readLine();
    if (urlType === 3) {
        GetOtherPage(url, path);
    }
}
DoTask();
```

The result:

```
3(input)
https://www.google.com(input)
output.html(input)
{}
{}
success
3(input)
https://www.google.com(input)
output.html(input)
{}
{}
success
```

Update: It seems that when you try to get the same url via one phantomJS process, phantomJS will get them in your disk cache, so it doesn't request the url the second time, so the resultjson and Headers are {}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property **response.url** is [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization), so it adds a trailing `'/'` to the one that was typed.

Since that comparison `response.url === url` is false, it never enters the `if`.

Testing with `https://www.google.com/` (with the trailing `'/'`), gives me the following output:

```
3
https://www.google.com/
output.html
{"Id":1,"Url":"https://www.google.com/","Time":"2016-07-29T03:56:24.294Z","ContentType":"text/html; charset=UTF-8","RedirectU
RL":"https://www.google.com.br/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=BNSaV_KoL6KB8QfJrYPoDA","Stage":"end","Status":302,"StatusText":"Found"}
{"Cache-Control":"private","Content-Type":"text/html; charset=UTF-8","Location":"https://www.google.com.br/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=BNSa
V_KoL6KB8QfJrYPoDA","Content-Length":"263","Date":"Fri, 29 Jul 2016 03:56:52 GMT","Alternate-Protocol":"443:quic","Alt-Svc":"
quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25\""}
success
```

<sub>Tested with phantomjs v2.1.1</sub>

Comment: Yep,it is a reason, but in my wrapper code,  i have done the normalization of the url. I have found the reason in my update. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think you can control the cache with the parameter [`disk-cache`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822617/how-do-i-make-phantom-js-cache-resources-like-a-normal-browser) or with the method [`page.clearMemoryCache`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390974/phantomjs-keeping-cache) (but I didn't tested it) :-)